# Jenkins accessing artifact from GitHub workflow job

Tags: github, jenkins, workflow, pipeline

I have a GitHub webhook triggering Jenkins when a commit is made to a branch.
Jenkins is using a Multibranch Pipeline.
When Jenkins runs its job it checkouts the commit which caused the webhook trigger.
Additionally, available are GIT_COMMIT and GIT_BRANCH in the Jenkins environment.

I would like the Jenkins pipeline to:

- Wait until the GitHub action has completed (it builds the code and stores the binary as a job artifact)
- Jenkins to download the binary artifact for the GitHub job

The information seems to be available in the payload (value of html_url field) sent by GitHub to Jenkins, but I do not understand how to access the webhook payload in the Jenkins pipeline.

Any help appreciated on either aspect of the problem.

I have tried accessing the environment in Jenkins, and modifying the triggers in GitHub

Comment: can anyone help us?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing.